# Python iteration, replace(), and strip()

Tags: python, replace, strip

As simple as I can make it:

I have written a python script to extract embed links from an api. I can easily return a list of embed links similar to this:

`[<embed>www.example.com/embed/4657889</embed>, <embed>www.example1.com/embed/789465/</embed>, <embed>www.example2.com/embed/132456/</embed>]`

But what I would like to do next is take this returned list and replace every `<embed>` with `<embed src="` as well as replace every `</embed>` with `">` ultimately creating a new list that looks like this:

`[<embed src="www.example.com/embed/4567889/>, <embed src="www.example1.com/embed/789456/>, <embed src="www.example.com/embed/123456/>]`

But as you can see, the word 'embed' is also in the url itself so I have to make sure not to touch that use of the word. I've tried replace(), trip(), a for loop, all with no luck. Anyone have any ideas of how I could implement this? Thank you ahead of time and hope everyone is staying healthy!

Comment: Replace `<embed>` instead of just `embed`

Comment: Use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression

```
import re

lst = ["<embed>www.example.com/embed/4657889</embed>",
      "<embed>www.example1.com/embed/789465/</embed>",
      "<embed>www.example2.com/embed/132456/</embed>"]

rx = re.compile(r'<embed>(.+?)</embed>')

new_lst = [rx.sub(r'<embed src="\1">', item) for item in lst]
print(new_lst)
```

Which yields

```
['<embed src="www.example.com/embed/4657889">', '<embed src="www.example1.com/embed/789465/">', '<embed src="www.example2.com/embed/132456/">']
```

Comment: Or without regex: `'<embed>www.example.com/embed/4567889/</embed>'.replace('<embed>', '<embed src="').replace('</embed>', '">')`

Comment: Why use regex instead of an actual XML parser?

Comment: @AMC: Imo, a parser is a bit overkill when OP has already the values in question in a list. But nothing wrong in using a parser, no.

Comment: That's true, although my assumption was that they would rewrite the rest of their program to make use of the XML parser.

Comment: @AMC: That would be the better alternative, yes.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm!! Can't thank you enough. I guess I have a new chore. To go do some studying on python regex!

Comment: @WBR: Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped you.